# PHP Fatal Error from json_decode inside try-catch

Tags: php, json

The following code throws me this exception:

```
$return = json_decode($result);
```

> Fatal error: Cannot access property started with '\0' in
>   file.php on line
>   36

I've read php documentation and some questions here, so I've tried this code:

```
try{
   $return = json_decode($result);
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {

   $json_error_code = json_last_error();
   echo $json_error_code . ",";
   $err.= 'JSON parse error';
   switch ($json_error_code) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
     $err = "NONE";
     break;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
     $err.= ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
     break;
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
     $err.= ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
     break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
     $err.= ' - Unexpected control character found';
     break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
     $err.= ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
     break;
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
     $err.= ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
     break;
    default:
     $err.= ' - Unknown error';
     break;
   }
   echo $err;
  }
```

It throws the same Fatal error - in a try-catch block!

Can someone help me solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Fatal error is fatal. It's not an exception. Fix the problem. What is `$result`?

Comment: Where is line 36 of the AsyncAlexExecutor.php file?

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem but you didn't create the variable error before concatenating the first value to it. `$err.= 'JSON parse error';` should probably be `$err = 'JSON parse error';`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes it throws an error before it even starts the catch.

Comment: @Kalmarivitch You are getting FATAL ERROR, not an exception. So, TRY & CATCH will not do any help.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart so how can I "catch" this Fatal error?

Comment: @Kalmarivitch You can't catch fatals. They are fatal, the script dies as soon as it's hit. You need to fix the actual issue. If you want help with that, provide what `$result` is and any other questions.

Comment: Check the code from given error log's Line number & trying to fig. out what could be the issue. Ex : If error is coming from ```$return = json_decode($result);``` then check what exactly data content in ```$result``` variable. Maybe there is some problem in that.

Comment: Can you show your json code?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly remove try catch block json_decode does not throw exceptions.
Secondly create $err change the line

```
$err.= 'JSON parse error';
```

to

```
$err= 'JSON parse error';
```

You try to do concatenate strings to variable that does not exists.

Remove also break from default: it's useless.

After you do it it should work.

Notice: If you want errors to behave like exceptions you need to use [own error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

If json_encode gives you fatal error then try reinstalling json extension and see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68546

Comment: That code would only have produced a warning, not the fatal error that's been described.

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot access property started with `

Comment: @JonStirling still, throws Fatal error: Cannot access property started with '\0' in file.php

Comment: It's fatal error not warning. Probably he has some non ascii char before accessing variable but I don't see the code that could produce this error in his code. But I give solution how to make it work and what are the problems.

Comment: @Robert What? Trying to concat to a non-existent variable will raise a warning. Not a fatal error. This answer is completely irrelevant.

Comment: talking about content of $result variable is irrelevant as well. The problem is with variable name not with the content of variable.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not true. Depending on what $result is, it could make all the difference.

Comment: $result 's content are not relevant. I need to know how to handle json_decode fatal erros.

Comment: @Kalmarivitch How many times to I have to say it. You _can't "handle" fatal errors_. You need to fix the cause of the fatal error.

Comment: @Kalmarivitch maybe the error comes from JSON extension have you tried to reinstall it? Check also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68546